# Pointer comparison

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Do pointers in C and C++ support comparison operators (`>`, `<`, etc.) in standard?

I want to compare array positions to be precise.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098966/universal-less-for-pointers-in-c-standard among others

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a contiguous array comparing memory offsets (pointers) is OK. If your array is implemented as a linked list (for example) the nodes could be all over memory so pointer comparison is nonsensical.

Comment: Note that the behavior of comparing pointers that don't point to the same array is undefined.

Comment: Note that in C++ the operator() of std::less<T*>, std::less_equal<T*>, std::greater<T*> and std::greater_equal<T*> are able to compare pointers to different object meaningfully.

Comment: @avakar: Technically, the behaviour is not _undefined_ (the result must of the comparison must be a bool, the implementation shouldn't randomly crash or anything); the result of the comparison is _unspecified_ - i.e. it could be true or false and the implementation doesn't have to document what the result is.

Comment: Charles, I checked and I stand corrected (it's section 5.9 in the standard). Thank you.

Comment: @CharlesBailey C99 6.5.9.5 (last sentence) "In all other cases, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be compared.

For example, see "Relational Operators" in standards for further information, 6.5.8 in C99, and 5.9 in old draft of C++ (2006-11).

Comment: With the caviat that the pointers must point to the same contiguous chunk of memory that was allocated in one allocation. Two random pointers can not be compared.