# Accessing pointer member data of struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to access the data of a pointer that is a member of a struct.

```
typedef struct
{
    int i1;
    int* pi1;
} S;


int main()
{
    S s1 = { 5 , &(s1.i1) };

    printf("%u\n%u\n" , s1.i1 , s1.pi1 ); //here is the problem 

return 0;
}
```

The problem lies in the second argument of printf. When i run the program i get the following result in console:  5 ...(next line) 2381238723(it's different every time).
This is correct, and the result is not unexpected. I have tried things like:

```
*(s1.pi1)
```

and

```
s1.*pi1
```

None of them works. Is there any operator in C or method to do this?

Comment: ask yourself what is the result of the expression `&(s1.pi1)` used to build your structure. Keep in mind that a pointer makes sense if it points to something, a pointer doesn't imply the existence of an associated object.

Comment: Maybe `S s1 = { 5 , &(s1.i1) };`?

Comment: `s1.pi1` _does_ access the "pointer member data of struct".  Curiously it appears the value `s1.pi1` is initialized with its address.

Comment: Yes i know i typed wrong. Though i still get the same result when i run it.

Comment: It was as you said i think. When i edited the code correctly and used *(s1.pi1) it worked! Sorry this is the second post i mess up.
But i am very thankful for your answers! It helped me solve the problem.

Comment: @Eijomjo well, **what** do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but I think you might have meant to do the following:

```
typedef struct
{
    int i1;
    int* pi1;
} S;


int main()
{
    // Take the address of s1.i1, not s1.pi1
    S s1 = { 5 , &(s1.i1) };

    // Dereference s1.pi1
    printf("%u\n%u\n" , s1.i1 , *s1.pi1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry i changed it now. Though i get the same result when i run it

Comment: @Eijomjo Did you make the other change, dereferencing `s1.pi1`?

Answer (score 1):

Going through [godel9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2905299/godel9)'s suggestion and comments, I infer that you have found a way to get the expected results

You wrote: I have tried things like:

`*(s1.pi1)` and `s1.*pi1`

I sense a li'l confusion there.

`mystruct.pointer` means that you have access to the pointer, now give,take,compare.. address.

`*(mystruct.pointer)` means that you have dereferenced the pointer,now giv, take,increment.. value.

Remember that pointers are just variables which store addresses([!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151377/what-exactly-is-a-c-pointer-if-not-a-memory-address/15151542#15151542)) but more versatile than the common ones.