# What's the definition of ++p where p is const char *p in C?

Tags: c, pointers

If I need to iterate over an array in C, I can do something like:

```
void uselessTest(const char *p)
{
    while(*p)
    {
        ++p;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering about what that means in detail:

- Does it tests, at every loop, `if (*p != null)` ?
- If it does `p = p + 1`, what does that mean? Is p a numeric value? `*p` should be the value pointed and `p` the address of the pointer? So in this loop `p` changes while `*p` remains the same?

Comment: This does not seem to iterate over any *array*, but more specifically over a C string, which is zero-terminated. (At the end of the function it points to the character after the last one.)

Comment: The terminology in C is a little mixed up for some terms. For example the term "null" can have two meanings, either as a null *pointer* or the null *character terminating a string. For your loop condition what is tested is not the null pointer but the null character.

Comment: Google "pointer arithmetic".

Comment: And regarding the `p++` expression, search for and read about *pointer arithmetic*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it tests, at every loop, if (*p != null) ?

I would say more correct is to say it checks if `*p!=0`.

> If it does p = p + 1, what does that mean? Is p a numeric value?

It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151377/what-exactly-is-a-c-pointer-if-not-a-memory-address) C standard does not define what pointer is internally. But in below example, I will assume p holds an address represented as integer (which usually is the case). In that case, in your above example, when you add one to it, `p` moves to the next
address, e.g., if `p` was 0x1000, after increment it would become 0x1001 (This is because size of `char` is 1, in case `p` was pointer to `int` it would move four bytes forward<sup>*</sup> -given size of integer is four).

> So in this loop p changes while *p remains the same?

No, indeed `*p` tries to dereference `p`, in other words, obtain contents of the object stored at address `p`. So of course if you change value of `p`, you may also get different content at new address. e.g., if initial value of `p` was 0x1000, after increment, it will be 0x1001, and `*p` will try to read value at 0x1001 which might be different from value stored at 0x1000.

<sup>* <sub>Look up pointer arithmetic for more details about that</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2):

It tests at each iteration if *p != null) and terminates the loop if it is null.

It increases the pointer, ergo, the pointer points to the next address. So using a loop like this, you can iterate over items in an array.

So basically what this loop does: it iterates over the characters in the array, until it reaches a terminating `\0` character. On each iteration, the pointer `p` is increased to point to the next character.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it tests, at every loop, if (*p != null) ?

There is no `null` in C. There is a NUL-terminator(`'\0'`) and `NULL`. The latter is associated with pointers.

The check is

```
if (*p != 0)
```

which is the same as

```
if (*p != '\0')
```

> If it does p = p + 1, what does that mean?

It moves the pointer `sizeof(*p)` bytes forward.

> Is p a numeric value?

`p` is a `const char*`, or in other words, a pointer to `char`.

> *p should be the value pointed and p the address of the pointer?

`*p` is the data which the pointer `p` points to and `p` is the address which the pointer points to (which is different from `p`'s address)

Comment: In ASCII there is `NUL`.  In C, there is the _null character_ `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it tests, at every loop, `if (*p != null)` ?

If you meant 0 or '\0', yes.

> If it does `p = p + 1`, what does that mean? Is p a numeric value? *p should be the value pointed and p the address of the pointer? So in this loop p changes while *p remains the same?

It advances the pointer to the next location that makes sense, thus according to pointer arithmetic. Yes, it contains a number which represents the address of the pointed object. Exactly; further, you cannot change the pointed value (`*p`) because it's `const`.

Comment: No, it's not "short-circuit" evaluation, that's what happens with the logical AND and OR operators. Doing `*p` is *short-hand* for `*p != 0`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, got confused. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: "Yes, it (`p`) contains a number"  Hmm, doubt you will find that in the C spec.  It certainly does not need to be a arithmetic type of number.

Comment: @chux I agree. Just for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

This is really basic C pointer usage.

`const char *p` means p in a pointer to `const char` => `p` can be modified but not `*p`

`while (*p)` is *by definition the same as `while (*p != 0)` so yes the loop does the test `*p == 0` on each iteration

`++p` increases pointer and as such is legal per my first remark

Conclusion : this code loops through a char array until pointed value is null - the *definition* of the end of a C string (null terminated char array)

Answer (score 2):

> "Does it tests, at every loop, if (*p != null) ?"

Correct

p is a pointer containing "addresses of type char". An address is a byte offset (offsets from 0).

p + 1 will increment to point to the next char address in memory. Since char is one byte long p will increment its byte offset by one. (In case of an int32 it will increment by 4, for example).
If p was initially 30, p+1 will be 31 for char, and 34 for int32 pointers.

In this loop p changes. Since *p is the value contained at the memory address pointed by p, it will also change (in general, it could be the case that it randomly keeps constant).

Answer (score 2):

`while(*p)` This reads byte/char pointed to by `p` and compares the read value against 0. That is it checks whether *p is equal to zero or not.

`++p;` This is same as `p = p + 1;` This increments `p` to point to next char.

In effect, since `p` points to an array of chars, the loop helps you iterate through all chars till it finds a null char. If `p` is a pointer to a string, this iterates through all chars in the string. null char (`\0`) is where a string ends.

| h | e | l | l | o | 0 |

Assume the string "hello", and `p` points to h, the loop iterates 5 times (for h, e, l, l, o), and comes out when it sees 0.