# C++: Operator overloading of < for pointers to objects

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pointers

I would like to compare two objects through their addresses. I tried operator overloading and it does not seem to work for pointers, but works for objects themselves. The following is the relevant code:

```
class C {
        public:
                int x;
};
.
.
.
bool operator <( C *ptr_c1, C *ptr_c2 )
{
        return ( (*ptr_c1).x < (*ptr_c2).x );
}
```

Comment: See these: * [Universal `less<>` for pointers in C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098966/universal-less-for-pointers-in-c-standard)
* [What are the operations supported by raw pointer and function pointer in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418068/what-are-the-operations-supported-by-raw-pointer-and-function-pointer-in-c-c)

Comment: @snjv: Are you saying that, given pointers to `C` you want to compare them, but for the comparison to be based on some member, such as `x`?

Comment: yes, that is exactly require!

Answer (score 11):

> I tried operator overloading and it does not seem to work for pointers,

Correct.

> but works for objects themselves.

Correct.

So what is the question?

Do you want to use pointers in a sorted container?

With:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct X
{
    int x;
};
```

C++ 11 and later

```
int main()
{
    X       x1; x1.x    = 5;
    X       x2; x2.x    = 6;

    auto compare = [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs){return lhs->x < rhs->x;};
    std::set<X*, decltype(compare)> plop(compare);

    plop.insert(&x1);
    plop.insert(&x2);
}
```

In C++ 03

```
struct XPTest
{
    bool operator()(X* const& lhs,X* const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs->x < rhs->x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X       x1; x1.x    = 5;
    X       x2; x2.x    = 6;

    std::set<X*,XPTest> plop;

    plop.insert(&x1);
    plop.insert(&x2);
}
```

Comment: Why do we have to use a new struct ? Cant we use the struct X ?

Comment: @Ediolot: You could. But that would be a bad idea. The second class passed to `std::set` is supposed to be a comparison class. Putting the test in `X` and then declaring `std::set<X, X>` does not seem very logical.

Comment: Can the same be achieved by overloading `operator<` for `X` itself?

Answer (score 5):

A pointer is a native C++ type and you can only overload operators for user defined types (i.e. classes).

If this was possible it would violate the principal of 'least surprise' and cause pointer comparisons to behave differently based on whether not your definition was visible. This would probably be very confusing.

If you want to use an alternative comparison for use in container or with algorithms, note that you can provide a replacement for the default `std::less` in most associative containers and algorithms that require a partial order.

Comment: Why is the change of behavior less "surprising" when you use template specialization of `std::less`?

Comment: @mastov: It's not legal to specialize `std::less` for raw pointers. Using another function object to _replace_ `std::less` should be less surprising because it needs to be explicitly specified.

Comment: Sure, something replacing `std::less` that is *not* a specialization would be less surprising (since it has to be used explicitly), I misread your answer there, I understood that you wanted to *specialize* `std::less`. Anyway, I couldn't find a reference for specialization of `std::less` for raw pointers being illegal. Who/what says it is?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(*obj1 < *obj2) { /* this should use the overloaded operator. */ }
```

Comment: I have the pointers in a priority_queue that in turn uses '<'.