# How do I create overloaded operators for boost pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading

From this post I see that you can't overload operators for pointers: [C++: Operator overloading of < for pointers to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419997/c-operator-overloading-of-for-pointers-to-objects)

But is there any way I could overload operators for boost pointers? For example:

```
  boost::shared_ptr<ClassB> operator||(boost::shared_ptr<ClassA> lhs, boost::shared_ptr<ClassA> rhs) {
    boost::shared_ptr<ClassB> returnVal = CreateClassBSharedPtr(lhs, rhs);
    return returnVal;
  }
```

When attempting this, I get an ambiguous overload error (it conflicted with the built in operator||(bool, bool)).  Any ideas to get around this?

**Edit: Adding some more details below as to why I'd like to do this.**

I'll try to explain what I'm attempting as best I can.  What I'd like to do is make a "validator" object for maps that can check if certain properties hold.  For example:

```
boost::shared_ptr<MyValidator> my_validator = IsEmpty("key name 1") && IsNotEmpty("key name 2") || HasNElements("key name 3", num)
```

Later, to validate a map:

```
if(my_validator.validate(some_map)) { ... }
```

I think I'm stuck with using pointers because I can't use pass by value (since I'm making use of polymorphism) and I can't use pass by const reference (since there would be temporary object created by nesting operators that would not exist later when trying to validate).

**Edit: Added a new question specific to my problem here:** [Implementation suggestions for creating an expression later used to evaluate the contents of a map in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441608/implementation-suggestions-for-creating-an-expression-later-used-to-evaluate-the)

Comment: not that it answers your question, but... **why would you do this**?!?

Comment: Following Evan's comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.8

Comment: So you really want to construct an expression, and then  later apply that expression to the contents of a map? If so, I would ask another, different question about that, leaving out the shared pointer stuff, which seems to be an implementation detail.

Comment: In other words, never ask about steps but about problems.

Comment: Yes, I understand your recommendations.  I was curious about this issue in any case, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can:

```
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"

template <class A>
bool operator||(boost::shared_ptr<A> lhs, boost::shared_ptr<A> rhs) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    boost::shared_ptr <int> a, b;
    bool x = a || b;
}
```

Whether you can do what you are doing in your example, I don't know, as I'm not sure what you are trying to do!

Comment: **Sorry about the poor formatting, can't figure out how to get this to look right**

Note that I'm trying to return a boost::ptr, and doing this:  


template <class A, class B>
boost::shared_ptr<B> operator||(boost::shared_ptr<A> lhs, boost::shared_ptr<A> rhs) {
    boost::shared_ptr<B> x;
    return x;
}
...
  boost::shared_ptr<int> a, b;
  boost::shared_ptr<int> c = a || b;


I get this error: 
 error: conversion from 'bool' to non-scalar type 'boost::shared_ptr<int>' requested

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work, at least it [works for me](http://ideone.com/rLJSr).

However, you will always run into the problems with ambiguous overloads when trying some user-defined conversions on `rhs` and `lhs`.

Answer (score 0):

Operator|| must always return a bool, so you can't (and for the sake of the sanity of your co-workers, shouldn't) do that.  I suggest you use a regular function and give it a name that reflects what you are trying to do.  GetValidatedPtr() or something simlar.

Comment: There is nothing that says operator || *must* return a bool, but of course it is good practice for it to do so.

Comment: Well, if the standard doesn't demand it, then I personally demand it!