# Implementation suggestions for creating an expression later used to evaluate the contents of a map in c++?

Tags: c++, validation, maps

My goal is to create a "validator" object for maps.  An example of how I'd like to use it:

```
MyValidator my_validator = (IsEmpty("key name 1") && DoesExist("key name 2"))
                           || HasNElements("key name 3", num)
```

Later:

```
if(my_validator.validate(some_map)) {
// do something
}
```

In this case, `my_validator.validate(some_map)` would return true if `some_map["key name 1"]` was empty and `some_map["key name 2"]` exists, or if `some_map["key name 3"]` had 3 elements.

Any implementation suggestions would be appreciated.

See this post for my prior question regarding an implementation I was attempting: [How do I create overloaded operators for boost pointers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440984/how-do-i-create-overloaded-operators-for-boost-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Using that expression syntax is going to make it very difficult. The way I've always done this in the past is to have an abstract Rule class from which I derive concrete rule types. I then add these to the validator:

```
Validator v;
v.add( new NotValueRule( "foo" ) );
v.add( new NotIntRule ) );
v.add( new BetweenRule( "a", "z" ) );
```

and then call the validate() function on the validator. This doesn't allow directly for ands and ors, but you can get round that with a couple of "fake" rules called AndRule and OrRule.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is generally called a Lambda. For now, you could look up [Boost::lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/lambda.html). In C++0x, lambda expressions will be directly supported by the language.