# Overloading operator < in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

it seems that overloading operators is not working for me, I am probably doing something wrong.

I've got this structure

```
typedef void (*fptr)(void);
struct Mystruct
{
    int id;
    int priority;
    double timeSaved;
    double aktivationTime;
    fptr eventPointer;
    MystructnextPtr;

    Mystruct(int id, int priority, double timeSaved, double aktivationTime, fptr eventPointer);
};
```

This operator:

```
bool operator <(const Mystruct& x, const Mystruct& y)
{
    return std::tie(x.aktivationTime, x.priority, x.timeSaved) < std::tie(y.aktivationTime, y.priority, y.timeSaved);
}
```

And am trying to execute this code:

```
Mystruct* struct1 = new Mystruct(5, 10, 0, 15.3, f1);
Mystruct* struct2 = new Mystruct(5, 10, 0, 14.3, fi);

if (struct1 < struct2)
{
    cout << "struct1 is smaller!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "struct2 is smaller!" << endl;
}
```

It ALWAYS says to me that struct1 is smaller, regardless of what is in those structures. What am doing wrong?

Comment: You're comparing the pointers and not the structs.  Try if (*struct1 < *struct2 )...

Comment: Better yet, don't use pointers here.

Comment: so how should I create the structures?

Comment: @TonyLee it says, that I don't have the back operator created.

Comment: `if (*struct1 < *struct2)`

Comment: post the code that yielded that or it didn't happen :-p... "I tried xyz and it yielded abc..."

Comment: @Dracke: "so how should I create the structures?" `Mystruct struct1(5, 10, 0, 15.3, f1);` is the conventional way. Save `new` for when you really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created an operator handling constant references to `Mystruct`. (`const Mystruct&`).  However you are using the comparator operator on non-const pointers to non-const `MyStruct` instances.

You have one real option:
 - deference your pointers `(*struct1 < *struct2)`

However also take a look here..
[C++: Operator overloading of < for pointers to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419997/c-operator-overloading-of-for-pointers-to-objects)

Comment: Option 1 is not viable. At least one operand must be a user-defined type.

Comment: you are correct amending answer.. always forget about that.