# Is is valid to construct std::set of pointer type?

Tags: c++

I want to store some pointers into std::set, but the standard guide says it's invalid.

> If two pointers p and q of the same type point to different objects that are > not members of the same object or elements of the same array or to different > functions, or if only one of them is null, the results of pq, p<=q, and  > p>=q are unspecified.

It seems the <, > operators are not supported by naive pointer type, as below.

```
Object * a = new Object;
Object * b = new Object;
a == b; // valid
a < b; //invalid
Object * arr = new Object[10];
&arr[3] == &arr[4]; // valid
&arr[3] < &arr[4]; // valid
```

How can I put pointers into std::set or key of std::map? Should I define some  comparison-supporting wrapper

*Edit 1*

[Some other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418068/what-are-the-operations-supported-by-raw-pointer-and-function-pointer-in-c-c/1418152#1418152) say that even though <, > are not directly supported by C++ pointers, std::less works fine with pure pointers(without any extra information). But I can't find any reference for that.

Comment: What I expect is just unique container of pointers, so comparing raw address is enough for me. I know I can use std::unordered_map for that, but anyway I should add hash function in that case

Comment: Yes. I think answer below solved my problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it is true that built-in operator `<` only works for pointers into the same array, `std::set` and `std::map` don't use that operator - they use `std::less`. This, in turn, is guaranteed to impose a total order on all pointers:

> **[comparisons]/2** For templates `less`, `greater`, `less_equal`, and `greater_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a strict total order that is consistent among those specializations and is also consistent with the partial order imposed by the built-in operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`.

Comment: I was wondering why `<` cannot compare pointers to elements to different arrays. Why can't it just compare the memory address like `std::less`

Comment: @GauravSehgal If I had to guess, I'd suspect it has something to do with [segmented memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation) architectures that were prevalent at the time C++ was being standardized.

Comment: @GauravSehgal different objects could have different storage and address schemes.