# Does a program with std::map<T*, U> have well-defined behaviour?

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, language-lawyer, strict-weak-ordering

[Comparing pointers to unrelated objects has unspecified results.](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#4)

That would seem to suggest that this program may have undefined behaviour, at the very least because we cannot guarantee a strict weak ordering on the key type:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 1;
    bool arbitrary = false;

    std::map<int*, bool> m{
       {&x, arbitrary},
       {&y, arbitrary}
    };
}
```

More generally, then, can we say that a map with pointer keys is a dangerous* proposition? Or is there some special rule we can lean on here?

<sup>* Academically speaking, that is; in reality I'm not aware of mainstream implementations that will actually raise hell over comparing arbitrary pointers.</sup>

Comment: The question is answered in [Is is valid to construct std::set of pointer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927571/is-is-valid-to-construct-stdset-of-pointer-type)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer You are right

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, because [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) default comparison operator is [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), which, unlike the standard comparison operator, is completely defined for pointer types.

> [[comparisons#2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/comparisons#2)
>
> For templates less, greater, less_­equal, and greater_­equal, the specializations for any pointer type yield a result consistent with the implementation-defined strict total order over pointers ([[defns.order.ptr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.order.ptr)).

The *implementation-defined strict total order over pointers* is defined in [[defns.order.ptr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.order.ptr) as:

> implementation-defined strict total ordering over all pointer values such that the ordering is consistent with the partial order imposed by the builtin operators <, >, <=, >=, and <=>

Comment: Oh yeah haha. Nice one

Comment: Interesting, that directly violates [\[expr.rel\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#4), no?

Comment: @rustyx As I understand this, the standard imposes implementation to have a strict total order over all pointers, but this order is not presented through built-in operators but only through `std::less`-like functors. So there are two different "orders" (one implementation-specific usable through `std::less`, and one for built-in operators), and they have to be consistent when both are defined (same-array / members of same object).

Comment: But it says "*order imposed by the **builtin operators < ...***" ;)

Comment: @rustyx The *"**implementation**-defined strict total order over pointers"* must be consistent with the standard-defined **partial** order imposed by the builtin operators.

Comment: @rustyx A valid implementation is allowed to produce `false` for **both** `p1 < p2` and `p2 < p1` when `p1` and `p2` do not fall into the scope defined by [expr.rel]/4, but **at least one of** `std::less{}(p1, p2)` or `std::less{}(p2, p1)` must be `true`.

Comment: @L.F. According to http://eel.is/c++draft/comparisons#2, even the `void`-specialization should provide a strict total order.

Comment: @Holt It's actually [LWG2450](https://wg21.link/LWG2450), which was resolved as of C++17. I gotta learn more ...

Answer (score 8):

[std::less](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) (default comparer of `std::map`) has special treatment about pointer allowing that:

> A specialization of `std::less` for any pointer type yields a strict total order, even if the built-in `operator<` does not.

And about

> can we say that a map with pointer keys is a *dangerous* proposition?

So it is fine in general.

Additional precaution should be taken with `const char*` key:

We compare pointers and not string content (mostly beginner confusions).

C-string literals with same content have no guaranty to be equals:

```
"literal" == "literal"; // Not guaranteed
"literal" < "literal"; // false .. or true
```

Comment: OTOH in a scope where a static variable is guaranteed to exist in one instance in the program, every source code instance of a literal string is guaranteed to have one well defined address, so `inline void *literal() { return "literal";}` guarantees that `literal()==literal()`. OTOH the same literal string in diff file static functions in diff TU have no such guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` use `std::less` that have a specialization for pointer type :

> A specialization of std::less for any pointer type yields a strict
>   total order, even if the built-in operator< does not. The strict total
>   order is consistent among specializations of std::less, std::greater,
>   std::less_equal, and std::greater_equal for that pointer type, and is
>   also consistent with the partial order imposed by the corresponding
>   built-in operators (<, >, <= and >=).

For a more specific description i leave you 2 links:

[std::less first link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)

[std::less second link](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/utility/functional/less.html)

Answer (score 1):

> that is; in reality I'm not aware of mainstream implementations that
>   will actually raise hell over comparing arbitrary pointers.

Depends on what *hell* means. Hell isn't just crashing right away or scrambling memory with random data. It could be giving indeterminate results to what should be a deterministic function.

GCC was known to optimize pointer comparisons on objects known to point to related (virtual) (sub) objects of different complete objects A and B: anything based on `&A` would compare differently to anything based on `&B`, even `&A+1`, even when the address were actually the same. I don't know if that was observed in C or in C++, but your question is pretty much C/C++ (and applies to `qsort` too).

That is, the result of a pointer comparison would depend on the known origin of a pointer. That mean that depending on optimization level, inlining context, translation unit, etc. a comparison could give different results.

So yes it could break down on at least some versions of a popular compiler if you did these pointer comparisons.

Which you don't as `std::map` is not defined in term `operator<` but in term of `std::less`.

Comment: Granted; "raise hell" I suppose is left-over wording from an earlier revision of the question when I thought the pointer comparison itself might have UB; a broken ordering still could but that's not what the quoted bit says. I should have updated that too. But if I had, I wouldn't have received this helpful addition :)