# How do I store addresses in a map in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, linked-list

I'm trying to find the intersection point between two linked lists. I already know how to solve the problem by calculating the absolute difference in length of the two lists and displacing one of the pointers. 
I want to know if it is possible to solve the question by storing addresses of each of the nodes along with a visited count in the map stores how many times the node has been visited.

```
int findMergeNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {
    map<int,int>m1;
    //map<int*,int>m1 ??
    //map<address,int>m1??
    SinglyLinkedListNode *temp = head1;
    while(temp!=nullptr) {
        m1[temp]++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp = head2;
    while(temp!=nullptr) {
        m1[temp]++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    for(auto it=m1.begin();it!=m1.end();it++) {
        if(it->second > 1) {
            temp = it->first;
            return temp->data;
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling and running the code? What happens when you do that?

Comment: Now if your second map has a million nodes and the first node is the intersection point, you wastefully go through that entire second linked list.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Agreed but my question was intended more towards storing addresses in a map and not efficiency per se. Wouldn't have noticed it without your saying so, though.

Comment: @ShrenikRaj Remember that the comment section is for comments, not answers.  I commented on your code and approach.

Comment: There is `std::set_intersection` if you want that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
map<SinglyLinkedListNode *, int> m1;
```

will do the trick. For each pointer to a `SinglyLinkedListNode`, you keep a number, the number of visits.

You can do even better with:

```
map<const SinglyLinkedListNode *, int> m1;
```

If you don't need to iterate over the pointers in order, another option is:

```
unordered_map<const SinglyLinkedListNode *, int> m1;
```

Some might claim this to be better as pointers don't have a useful order.

Comment: Thanks, this was way too trivial.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I added an answer explaining why, and with a fix.

Comment: It seems that the `map` version might not be UB after all. The `unordered` version is still better though :)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution might be to use:

```
std::map<SinglyLinkedListNode const *, int> m;
```

However, this suggests that the relative ordering of the pointers that are used as keys has some meaning, which is not the case here (and rarely ever is).

A slightly better solution would be to use:

```
std::unordered_map<SinglyLinkedListNode const *, int> m;
```

which suggests (correctly) that only uniqueness of the pointer values used as keys is relevant, and not their relative ordering.

Comment: Nitpick, map use `class Compare = std::less<Key>`, not `<`. But yeah, it's still UB. A conversion to `uintptr_t` might help?

Comment: Why do you say it's UB? This seems to indicate it should be fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418152/23649

Comment: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/20/std-less-nightmare/

Comment: although, in practice, for normal platforms, I've never had an issue using < on pointers

Comment: @jtbandes Hmm, I'm not completely sure. I'll have to dig deeper. Also, I'm not saying comparing pointers is UB, just unspecified. UB comes from not satisfying the requirements of `map`. But I might be wrong.

Comment: But since that map uses `std::less<Key>`, doesn't that mean it gets a strict total order, even if the built-in `<` might not provide a total order?

Comment: @jtbandes Yes, this seems to be the case. While the ordering might be different for different runs of the program, the requirements of `map` are still satisfied. I'll edit the answer, thanks.