# C++ - adding string key to map with const char* key creates new element instead of modifying

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a simple `map` with `const char*` key and `bool` value, and I have preadded keys, but when I try to modify a value with a string,  it creates a new entry, not edits an existing entry, and I have both with same key name.

```
map<const char*, bool> test=
    {
        {"Test", false},
        {"test2", false}
    };

string s = "Test";
test[s.c_str()] = true;
```

Gives me map test with

```
{"Test", false},
{"test2", false},
{"Test", false;}
```

[image: map]

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `0x005331B0`, `0x005331B8`, and `0x00BBF9C4` are all separate keys.

Comment: The key isn't the string, but the value of the pointer variable (like: 0x203348).

Comment: You're mapping a memory address key to a bool; not a string to a bool. The address from the literal `"Test"` is not the same as the address from `s.c_str()`. The question to ask yourself is why your map isn't `std::map<std::string, bool>`.

Comment: _"i try to modify key"_ - You are trying to modify the _value_, not the _key_.

Comment: This is pretty much a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25123055/315052

Comment: I'm 110% sure that you really want `map<string, bool>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want have C strings as keys you need to provide a user defined comparator since otherwise the map will compare the actual pointer values, not the C strings they point at.

Example:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

// a comparator class for C strings
struct cstring_less {
    bool operator()(const char* lhs, const char* rhs) const {
        return std::strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    // supply the comparator as the third template parameter:
    std::map<const char*, bool, cstring_less> test = {
        {"Test", false},
        {"test2", false}
    };
    
    std::string s = "Test";
    test[s.c_str()] = true;

    for(auto&[k,v] : test) {
        std::cout << k << ' ' << v << '\n';
    }
}
```

I really suggest that you use `std::string` as *Key* though.

The current `map` can't be used if any of the C strings (that are not string literals) you store pointers to have gone out of scope. The pointers you store are then "dangling" and dereferencing them would make the program have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Sound advice at the end of this, to be sure. If the order of insertions were opposite (`s.c_str()` were keyed *first*) and `s` had deeper automatic scope (say, from a function or a loop body), the map would be left with a dangling pointer as a key.

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed. That'd be terrible for sure!