# Strict weak ordering on pointer values

Tags: c++, set, strict-weak-ordering

Consider the following struct:

```
struct Foo {
  const Bar* x;
  const Bar* y;

  Foo(const Bar* _x, const Bar* _y = nullptr) : x(_x), y(_y) { assert(x); }
}
```

How do we define a strict weak ordering on x and y so that the object can be used within a std::set? Note that y can be a null pointer. As mentioned in [Using std::less with nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811034/using-stdless-with-nullptr) the behavior of std::less on null pointers is <strike>undefined</strike> unspecified. Will the following solution be sufficient?

```
bool operator<(const Foo& rhs) const {
  uintptr_t numX = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(x);
  uintptr_t numY = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(y);

  uintptr_t numRhsX = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(rhs.x);
  uintptr_t numRhsY = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(rhs.y);

  return std::tie(numX, numY) < std::tie(numRhsX, numRhsY);
}
```

EDIT: If not what is the proper way (e.g. how to combine std::less with std::tie)?

Comment: I would guess that this would have the same issue as `std::less` since they both might compare `nullptr` with `operator<` which the linked question says is unspecified.

Comment: The linked answer does _not_ assert that `std::less` on `nullptr` is "undefined". It specifically says "unspecified", which is different.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) goes into the difference between unspecified and undefined behavior.

Comment: On most implementations nullptr is a value equivalent to zero.

Comment: Being unspecified is different from being undefined. As long as you know that platform you are coding it for has nullptr as 0, and this is OK for your set, using `std::less` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `std::less<Bar*>` is sufficient (but using `operator<` is not). The pointer specializations of `std::less` (as [the accepted answer to "Using std::less with nullptr"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28811449/147845) points out) guarantee a *total ordering*. Comparison with `nullptr` is *unspecified*, meaning the standard does not impose a *particular* ordering, but `std::less` must still produce *a* total ordering (and for a given pointer `p`, `p < nullptr` necessarily produces the same value every time).

Since a total ordering is stronger than a weak ordering, using `std::less` is sufficient in your case.

> EDIT: If not what is the proper way (e.g. how to combine std::less with std::tie)?

There is no neat way, unfortunately. Since `std::tie` returns an `std::tuple`, and comparison on tuples is defined in terms of `operator<` on their values (rather than `std::less`), you can't really use `std::tie` here. To use `std::less`, you'd have to do it manually:

```
bool operator<(const Foo& rhs) const {
  if (std::less<>{}(x, rhs.x))
    return true;
  if (std::less<>{}(rhs.x, x))
    return false;
  return std::less<>{}(y, rhs.y);
}
```

---

As an aside, your current implementation (reinterpreting the pointers as integers) also produces a total ordering (obviously, since you're comparing integers) but instead of *unspecified* behavior you'll have *implementation-defined* behavior (from the `reinterpret_cast`).

Comment: std::less only takes 2 parameters. How do I combine them then?

Comment: @fliX: There's no good way using `std::tie` since `std::tuple` is specified to use the built-in `operator<`.