# Why does const_casting a heap.top() of priority_queue have undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++17, priority-queue, undefined-behavior, const-cast

I've made a simple Huffman encoding program to output individual encodings for characters and save the encoded file. This was for an assignment, and I was told that using `const_cast` on `heap.top()` is considered undefined behavior if we `heap.pop()` afterwards, but I'm not sure I understand why.

I've read [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) regarding the `std::pop_heap` which is the underlying function called when we call `heap.pop()` and I believe that a `nullptr` in the comparison is still defined and understood. It doesn't seem to function abnormally to me when I debugged it.

Here's an example

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T> void print_queue_constcast(T& q) {
    while(!q.empty()) {
        auto temp = std::move(const_cast<int&>(q.top()));
        std::cout << temp << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template<typename T> void print_queue(T& q) {
    while(!q.empty()) {
        std::cout << q.top() << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::priority_queue<int> q1;
    std::priority_queue<int> q2;
 
    for(int n : {1,8,5,6,3,4,0,9,7,2}){
        q1.push(n);
        q2.push(n);
    }
        
    print_queue(q1);
    print_queue_constcast(q2);
    
    
}
```

Could anyone explain what is actually going in the backgroun that'd be undefined behavior or that would cause this to fail under certain circumstances?

Comment: A link to another SO site isn't as good as putting your code in the question.

Comment: Make a [mcve] please...

Comment: Edited the question accordingly. I didn't think this is a question requiring code to be ran, as the code runs correctly. This is rather a generic question regarding coding practices and undefined behavior henceforth I only included an example to show what I mean.

Comment: Every question about code should have a [mcve]. As the person asking the question, you're generally not qualified to know what is and isn't relevant. Let us make that decision, after seeing your reproducing code! Otherwise you're making us spend more of our time on guessing :(

Comment: Understood and will keep that in mind, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Great, no worries

Comment: You should exchange the `int` for `shared_ptr` though - the answer will be different. So you've changed the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr: Maybe; maybe not.**

---

#### Language-level safety

Like a set, a priority_queue is in charge of ordering its elements. Any modification to an element would potentially "break" the ordering, so the only safe way to do that is via the container's own mutating methods. (In fact, neither one actually provides such a thing.) Directly modifying elements is dangerous. To enforce this, these containers only expose `const` access to your elements.

Now, at the language level, **the objects won't actually have a static type of `const T`; most likely they're just `T`s**. So modifying them (after a `const_cast` to cheat the type system) doesn't have undefined behaviour in that sense.

---

#### Library-level safety

However, **you are potentially breaking a condition of using the container**. The rules for priority_queue don't ever actually say this, but since its mutating operations are defined in terms of functions like [`push_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [`pop_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap), your use of such operations will break preconditions of *those* functions if the container's ordering is no longer satisfied after your direct mutation.

Thus your program will have undefined behaviour *if* you break the ordering and later mutate the priority_queue in such a way that depends on the ordering being intact. If you don't, technically your program's behaviour is well-defined; however, in general, you'd still be playing with fire. **A `const_cast` should be a measure of last resort.**

---

#### So, where do we stand?

The question is: did you break the ordering? What's the state of the element after moving from it, and is the ordering satisfied by having an object in that state at the top of the queue?

- Your original example uses `shared_ptr`s, and we know from the documentation that a moved-from `shared_ptr` turns safely into a null pointer.
- The default `priority_queue` ordering is defined by `std::less`, which yields a strict total order over raw pointers; `std::less` on a `shared_ptr` will actually invoke its base case of `operator<`, but [that in turn is defined to invoke `std::less` on its raw pointer equivalent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp).
- Unfortunately, **that doesn't mean that a null shared_ptr is ordered "first"**: [though `std::less`'s pointer ordering is strict and total, where null pointers land in this ordering is unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28811388/4386278).
- So, it is unspecified as to whether your mutation will break the ordering, and therefore **it is unspecified as to whether your `pop()` will have undefined behaviour**.

(The MCVE example with `int` is safe because `std::move` on an `int` has no work to do: it'll just copy the `int`. So, the ordering remains unaffected.)

---

#### Conclusion

I would agree with what was presumably your driving rationale, that it is unfortunate `pop()` doesn't return you the popped thing, which you could then `move` from. Similar restrictions with sets and maps are why we now have [node splicing features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) for those containers. There is not such a thing for a priority_queue, which is just a wrapper around another container like a vector. If you need more fine-grained control, you can substitute that for your own which has the features you need.

Anyway, **for the sake of a `shared_ptr` increment (as in your original code), I'd probably just take the hit of the copy**, unless you have some really extreme performance requirements. That way, you *know* everything will be well-defined.

Certainly, for the sake of an `int` copy (as in your MCVE), a `std::move` is *entirely* pointless (there are no indirect resources to steal!) and you're doing a copy anyway, so the point is rather moot and all you've done is to create more complex code for no reason.

**I would also recommend not writing code where you have to ask whether it's well-defined**, even if it turns out it is. That's not ideal for readability or maintainability.

Comment: @Jack Please review my edit - I have had to change my answer somewhat

Comment: It's all good! Thank you for the extensive answer, I understand where I stand now with the code, both in regards to the simpler int example and one with a shared_ptr. In my case it was actually undefined behavior as I used a custom comparator that didn't account for nullptr

Comment: Heh, another hidden facet. So a direct answer to your question may even have been wrong, because you left out another crucial detail! See what I mean about MCVEs....