# Is one of operator<(HANDLE, HANDLE) or std::less<HANDLE> well-defined?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++14, language-lawyer

I want to use a Windows `HANDLE` (a thread handle) as key in a `std::map`. For this, I need a less-than operator that is well-defined for the type `HANDLE`.

Pointer types `T*` can be used as keys for `std::map` only if the comparator `std::less<T*>` is specified, because the builtin `operator<(T*, T*)` (and henceforth `std::less<>`) does not provide a total order.

Implementationwise, we know that `HANDLE` is actually typedefed as a pointer type. Therefore, `std::less<HANDLE>` looks like a safe bet. But I consider it just an implementation detail that `HANDLE` is implemented as a pointer type. (And by inspecting actual `HANDLE` values in the debugger,  it can be clearly seen that they are not genuine pointer values.)

Are there any formal guarantees that can be derived from the C++ standard and the Windows API documentation that would allow me to use `HANDLE` as a key in `std::map`?

Comment: What's important is the *type*, not the actual *value*. A `HANDLE` really is of type `void*`. If a total order exists for `void*`, then you can use it as a key in a `std::map`. Keep in mind, that thread handles do get re-used after a thread object has been disposed.

Comment: @IInspectable Can you cite the documentation that states that `HANDLE` is a pointer type?

Comment: [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types).

Comment: Concerning _because the builtin `operator<(T*, T*)` (and henceforth `std::less<>`) does not provide a total order._ [SO: Universal less<> for pointers in C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099080/7478597) It's about C++03 but I really would wonder if such useful feature/requirement has been removed from more recent standards... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff - Spoiler: it's true for every C++ version since.

Comment: @j6t: "*Can you cite the documentation that states that HANDLE is a pointer type?*" Can you cite the documentation that states that HANDLEs have an order, rather than just being able to equality-test them? Because it seems to me that, by wanting to detect an order *at all*, you're already relying on the specifics of how a `HANDLE` is implemented.

Comment: @NicolBolas Since `HANDLE` is documented to be `void*`, an order is implied. Yes, the implementers restrict themselves to a certain implementation (and so guarantee properties---such as an order---that would otherwise not be needed) by documenting it publically, but that is not my problem ;) On the contrary, it is very useful.

Comment: @j6t: So if it is documented to be a `void*`, and it is required by the C++ standard that pointers have a total order accessible through `std::less`... what's your problem? How many more "formal guarantees" do you need?

Comment: @NicolBolas That's all the guarantees I want. Didn't I say that already...?